# Definition of Unipotent in Positive Characteristic

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$ whose characteristic is $p>0$.  Can $\mathcal{U}(G)$, the set of unipotent elements of $G$, be characterized as all elements $g\in G$ such that $g^{p^t}=1$ for some $t\in\mathbb{N}$?  If not, what is $\mathcal{U}(G)$?  If so, what are equivalent definitions of $\mathcal{U}(G)$ and why are they equivalent?

I'm just trying to grow in my understanding of the definition of unipotence.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It might be useful to cite exactly which definition of unipotent element of an affine algebraic group you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More "intrinsically", although you still need an embedding, is to embed $G \to GL(k[G])$. (We assume $k$ is algebraically closed). Here $k[G]$ is the ring of regular functions on $G$, and $G$ acts on $k[G]$ by
$$(g\cdot f)(x) = f(g^{-1}x)$$

Of course, $k[G]$ is an infinite dimension vector space, but you can show that it is the direct limit of finite dimensional $G$-stable subspaces. An unipotent element in $GL(k[G])$ is then defined to be an element unipotent on any restriction to the finite dimensional $G$-stable pieces.

But then for this definition to be used, you would need to check that under a morphism of algebraic groups, unipotent element gets sent to a unipotent one. Also for $GL_n$, unipotence in the usual sense is the same as this sense.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  I can see that $k[G]$ can be written as a union of finite-dimensional $G$-stable subspaces.  Why do we define $g$ to be unipotent if it is unipotent on these pieces?  Why can't we just define it to be unipotent as an element of $GL(k[G])$, i.e., if $g-1$ is nilpotent as an element of $End(k[G])?$  I'm not sure where the definition of unipotence breaks down for invertible endomorphisms of infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @Jared, I didn't study the concept of nilpotence in functional analysis so I'm not sure if there's working definition there. Here naively one problem would be what the definition of nilpotence is. If $n$ is nilpotent means that $n^k = 0$ for some $k$, it is apparently stronger than the restriction-to-finite-dim-subspace-is-unipotent definition, and is perhaps too restrictive to be useful. The restriction definition allows one define Jordan decomposition directly from the finite-dimensional theory, and perhaps is an advantage here.

Answer (score 3):

The set of unipotent elements are indeed the elements whose orders are some power of the characteristic of the field.

To see this, let $g\in G$ and embed $G$ in some general linear group $H$ over the field $k$. Let $p$ be the characteristic of $k$.

Since the order of the image of $g$ in $H$ is a power of $p$ if and only if the order of $g$ is a power of $p$, we just need to show that a matrix over a field of characteristic $p$ is unipotent if and only if it has order a power of $p$.

Let $A$ be a unipotent matrix, so $(A-I)^m = 0$ for some $m$. Let $n$ be given such that $p^n\geq m$. Then we have $0 = (A - I)^{p^n} = A^{p^n} - I$ so $A$ has order a power of $p$.

On the other hand, if we assume that $A^{p^n} = I$ for some $n$ then we have $(A - I)^{p^n} = A^{p^n} - I = 0$ so $A$ is unipotent.

Comment: For arbitrary characteristic, can we also embed $G$ into some general linear group to recover the unipotents?  That is, do we just assume the elements of $G$ are matrices and define unipotent elements as we would with matrices ($I+N$ for some nilpotent $N$)?  Do we lose anything from this point of view?  It would be nice to have an intrinsic definition of a unipotent element.

Comment: @Jared I am not aware of a definition of unipotent that does not go along the lines of "for any embedding into a general linear group...".

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unipotent_element#Unipotent_algebraic_groups for a definition that does not go along those lines